# [Vue warn]: (deprecation ATTR_FALSE_VALUE)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, element-plus

I migrate to Vue3 and I got this Vue warn, I don't really understand how to solve it.
That happend when I use el-button of element-plus library.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF6Tk.png)

The code:

```html
<div>
                <el-button
                  style="font-size: 30px"
                  class="element-btn"
                  type="primary"
                  circle
                  @click="buttonsController('add-button')"
                >
                  <div>
                    <el-icon :size="30"><Plus /></el-icon>
                    <p style="margin-top: 15px">Add</p>
                    <p style="margin-top: -10px">Dates</p>
                  </div>
                </el-button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a breaking change in Vue 3 that is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/attribute-coercion.html#overview) (point 2 in the overview).

> BREAKING: No longer removes attribute if the value is boolean false. Instead, it's set as attr="false". To remove the attribute, use null or undefined.

If you want to get rid of the warning, you should set the attribute value to `null` or `undefined` instead of `false`. Otherwise vue will apply the attribute with `false` instead of removing it.

### Example

```html
<!-- 
  if your variable contains `true` or `false`
  you need to make sure, the false case is
  passed as `null` or `undefined` to the attribute binding.
-->
<div :aria-disabled="myVariable || null"></div>
```

Comment: I still  have an error... I don't really understand what to change in the code that I post here.

Comment: I think you cannot do anything about it, as it seems to be part of the `el-button`. Do you use a library for the elements? Maybe there is a newer version of the library?